# Can I use "philosophy" as an adjective to indicate it's not "philosiphical"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, terminology, grammaticality-in-context

Dictionaries I've gone through don't seem to allow to use the names of sciences as adjectives. Even though, is it standard to use for ex. "philosophy terminology" instead of "philosophical terminology" to indicate I'm not talking about an abstract terminology but about the terminology used in philosophy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most nouns can be used attributively (i.e., as adjectives). There is nothing wrong with a "philosophy teacher" for example, and there is a reason for this, as a "philosophical teacher" doesn't have the same meaning. (A teacher of art can be philosophical.)

In the case of terminology, I don't see a need. "Philosophical terminology" means "word and expressions used in philosophy" and I don't need to use "philosophy terminology". A quick scan of Google shows that "philosophy terminology" and "philosophy term" are not used.

> Noumenon is Kant's philosophical terminology. It is sometimes called thing in itself.

---

> Nous [...] is a philosophical term for the faculty of the human mind ...

Comment: I couldn't find a better example but - in theory - is "blablalogical term" closer to the "term described blablalogically" and "blablalogy term" closer to the "term used in blablalogy"?

Comment: +1 Nice answer.   @Probably: Terminology cannot be **biological** in the sense of "being alive", so there's no *need* to say *biology terminology*, no need to disambiguate "the terminology which is alive" from "terminology used in Biology". **biological terminology** is fine. **biology terminology** is not the better choice. But it is a valid choice.

Comment: But sometimes you do need to *eliminate* a choice: **a scatology term** versus **a scatological term**.

Comment: @TRomano I hope it's clear I've intensionally used a non-existing branch of science "blablalogy" to indicate that I'm asking theoretically.

Comment: @Probably: it is very clear; indeed, your theoretical bent is at the heart of the problem. You're trying to devise a general-purpose rule, but as the **scatology/scatological** example shows, you need to know the meaning of the words *as they are used*.  Meaning is not theoretical but practical.

Comment: @TRomano I've used "theoretical" to refer to "gramatically correct". But the difference between scatology/scatological seems to be an exception to me, since it bears a metaphorical meaning. But thanks, I understand you.